# How do you properly use setTargetAspectRatio?

Tags: android, androidx, android-camerax

I am relatively new to developing on android and I am trying to implement a camera feature. I am using this page as a guide https://www.journaldev.com/30132/android-camerax-overview.

The section of code below is what I am having trouble with.

```
Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen

PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
```

When a Rational is passed into setTargetAspectRatio, Android Studio gives the error 'Rational cannot be converted into AspectRatio.

According to [the android developer page](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/PreviewConfig.Builder#setTargetAspectRatio(androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio)) setTargetAspectRatio accepts the object AspectRatio, so I tried this:

```
AspectRatio aspectRatio = new AspectRatio(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
```

However I then get the error, on this line saying 'AspectRatio() has private access in androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio'. 
I am not sure what this error means as I have imported androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio normally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the tutorial you're following is using a pretty old version (alpha02) of the camerax library. The current version is beta01, and many things have changed between these versions.

> 'AspectRatio() has private access in
>   androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio'. I am not sure what this error means
>   as I have imported androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio normally.

`AspectRatio` does indeed have a private constructor at the moment (and since a couple of versions ago), this restriction is to push you to only use one of the supported ratios `RATIO_4_3` or `RATIO_16_9`, meaning that configuring the preview's aspect ratio looks like this:

```
final Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(RATIO_16_9)
        .build()
```

Note that if you're only looking to add a basic view finder in your app, it is recommended to use cameraX's `PreviewView`, it makes setting up a camera preview easier, you can checkout how to do this from [the official cameraX docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview).